# A Acdx.Dll In My Reference Is Getting Vanished From The References Folder in visual studio If I Debug The Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, autocad

I am trying to develop an application for autocad.

i am using the following namespaces :

```
 System;
 System.IO;
System.Text;
 System.Collections;
 System.Windows.Forms;
 System.Collections.Generic;
 System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.ComponentModel;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.Customization;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsSystem;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.LayerManager;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.DataExtraction;
 Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
```

Among these namespaces, if i add a ACDX.dll, intellisense is able to detect the Autodesk.AutoCAD.DataExtraction namespace and if i debug the solution then i am not able to see acdx.dll in my refrences tab and even the namespace Autodesk.AutoCAD.DataExtraction is throwing an error saying that  "The type or namespace name 'DataExtraction' does not exist in the namespace 'Autodesk.AutoCAD' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I have the following references added in my project:

```
ac32bitappserver.dll
AcCoreMgd.dll
AcCui.dll
AcDbMgd.dll
acdbmgdbrep.dll
AcDx.dll
AcMgd.dll
acmnuparser.dll
AcMr.dll
AcTcMgd.dll
AcWindows.dll
AdWindows.dll
managedmc3.dll
```

Can u please help me out in resolving this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: You might start by checking that the project settings match the dll 'bitness' (If you are using a 32 bit dll, you should set your project settings to x86, in both debug and release, if it's a 64 bit dll, set it to x64)

Comment: Thank u...i have checked it...i have checked it, both the dll's and the project is in x86 32 bit.how can i furthur investigate.

Comment: The only other times I've seen that message were if I used the "Client Profile" (Project->Properies->Target Framework) on a DLL that didn't support it, if I didn't set my output path correctly (Project-> Properties->Build), or didn't set "Copy Local" to true on the reference  (Right Click on the reference -> Properties)